# Adding a variable name to a JSON list?

Tags: javascript, python, arrays, json

I'm writing this in Python and I want to be able to modify this JSON file

from this,

```
{
"name": "UVIDOCK",
"date": "03/14/2018",
"cola": "18:18:00",
"colb": "6.70000"
}
```

to this

```
window.data = {
"name": "UVIDOCK",
"date": "03/14/2018",
"cola": "18:18:00",
"colb": "6.70000"
}
```

Appreciate the help in advance.

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: Does it matter that the result will no longer be valid JSON format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So do you want a string with your JSON and a variable name? Assuming yes, but keeping in mind that it will not be a valid JSON, the solution will be:

```
import json
data = { "name": "UVIDOCK", "date": "03/14/2018", "cola": "18:18:00", "colb": "6.70000" }
jsonString = "window.data = " + json.dumps(data)
print (jsonString)

## Output: window.data = {"name": "UVIDOCK", "date": "03/14/2018", "cola": "18:18:00", "colb": "6.70000"}
```